# CoreData Model within Swift Package

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am trying to put a CoreData model into a Swift Package to extract my model code / classes from my main codebase.

I have done the following to recreate the issue I'm having from scratch:

- Create a new swift package called SampleModelPackage (File -> New -> Swift Package)
- Created a Core Data Model Definition File (Create File -> New -> File | iOS -> Core Data -> Data Model)
- Saved it in the Sources/SampleModelPackage directory alongside the auto-generated SampleModelPackage.swift

Now - when I attempt to open the Model.xcdatamodelId file in Xcode, it just shows me a "Version" icon (see screenshot), whereas creating a Core Data Model file in a Project or Framework will allow me to edit the model.

The second / follow up question would be how would I then extend the code-gem'd model files as normal? And how would I load that model definition (normally I would use a Bundle ID and the model file name)

I have tried adding the model file to the resources array of the Package.swift file (using .process and using .copy) as described on this page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package

Or more generally, is this even possible? (this article https://ishabazz.dev/blog/2020/7/5/using-core-data-with-swift-package-manager seems to imply that packaging core data models like this is possible)

(I am using Xcode 12.4)

[image: Exhibit A]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create your Core Data model in an ordinary Xcode project, then you can create your package and drag the model to it. (This is also what was done in the linked article if you look carefully even though it was not clearly described).

I believe the the best thing is to manually generate the source code files for your entities and add them to your package. You load the model using `Bundle` but instead of `Bundle.main` you use `Bundle.module`

Comment: So in order to edit the model file, you need to drag it to a project, edit it, then drag it back? ie. there's no way to see the contents of it when it's a part of a package?

Comment: That is not what I said, read the first line again. Once you have it in the package you can edit it.

Comment: You can create the model directly in the package, but you have to open and close the project after you create it.

Comment: @JohnSlade I just tested this and it works exactly as you said. Thanks for the update, this will make it easier to create a Core Data library for future projects.

Comment: Xcode 14.1 - You can't drag database model from project to package. If you try - nothing happens, model remains at the same place inside main project

Comment: @PeteStreem See the comment above from John Slade, maybe it will help you

Comment: xcode 14.3 - The operation is impossible. Pls document better, add video to the procedure or a more detailed instructions.

Comment: @FrancescoPiraneoG. Check the upvoted comment above from John for an easier solution

Answer (score 3):

Put your `Core Data Model` file into a directory named `Resources`, resulting in your file residing at `Sources/MyLibrary/Resources`.

In your case, it is `Sources/SampleModelPackage/Resources/Model.xcdatamodeld`.[image]